# PHP pagination fetchAll() and LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, limit, fetchall

This code work well on first page, but seems that LIMIT don't affect FetchAll().
So my question is:
Do fetchAll() have some optional argument that limit number of rows?
Or suggest my a better way to solve this problem.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
$rowsCount = $connection->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test')->fetchColumn();
$page = 1;
$perPage = 10;
if ( isset( $_GET["page"] ) and $_GET["page"] >= 1 and $_GET["page"] <= 10 ) {
    $page = (int) $_GET["page"];
  }
$beginning = ($page-1) * $perPage;
$end = $page * $perPage;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test LIMIT $beginning, $end";

?>
<table border = '2'>
<tr>
    <th width="30%">ID</th>
    <th width="70%">TEXT</th>
</tr>
<?php
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($connection->query($sql)->fetch());
// echo $sql;
// echo '<pre>';
foreach ($connection->query($sql) as $value) {
    echo '<tr height ="50px"><td>' . $value['id'] . '</td><td>' .   $value['text'] . '</td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>
    <p>
    <?php if($page > 1){ ?>
        <a href="pagination.php?page=<?php echo $page-1;?>" >Previous</a>
    <?php } ?>
        <a href="pagination.php?page=<?php if($page < ceil($rowsCount/$perPage)){ echo $page+1;} else {echo 1;}?>" >Next</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not `LIMIT beginning, end` but rather `LIMIT beginning, maxrows`.

Answer (score 0):

correct this line:

```
$end = $page * $perPage;
```

with:

```
$end = $perPage;
```

Or change your sql string to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test LIMIT $beginning, $perPage";
```